# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

My app is crashing

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting, use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path).

When I try to reload a single cell of my `tableView`, this is the button that I press to reload the cell

```
 @IBAction func reloadCell(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .right)

    }
```

and these are my **cellForRow** and **DidSelectRow**

```
   public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: resueIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.myCellNumber.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
            cell.refButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.refButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CourseClass2.reloadCell(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            let place = sortedArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.update(place: place)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

             if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
                loadPlaces(false)
            }
            print("CellForRow Call")
            return (cell)


        }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


           tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        })
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: indexPath)

        }
```

adding a breakpoint I saw that the app crash at this line in **DidSelectRow**.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why did you write in didSelect "let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell"? This line is meant for creating a cell not to get one.

Comment: so i have to change or delete it?  i wrote it to identify the cell i'm going to press

Comment: if want that particular cell (pressed one) then u can use : cellForRowAtIndexPath to get that cell simply .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `didSelectRowAt` method should be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast", sender: indexPath)

}
```

And if you want to identify your cell in your `didSelectRowAt` method. You can that with:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {

}
```

In your `didSelectRowAt` method.